# How to improve the code JS (Jquery)? A simple dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

How to edit code, to close the dropdown menu on second click.
In page I have many dropdowns.

```js
$('.dropdown').on('click', function() {
  var active = 'active';

  $(document).on('click', function() {
    $('.dropdown').removeClass(active);
  });

  $('.dropdown').removeClass(active);
  $(this).toggleClass(active);
  return false;
});
```

```css
.dropdown {
  margin: 50px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  background: #333;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown ul {
  display: none;
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: -120%;
  left: -100%;
}

.dropdown.active ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

As shown in example, just want to add to the menu from closing up when you click on the square.

Answer (score 2):

Just a simple line will suffice

```
$('.dropdown').on('click',function() {
  $(this).find("ul").toggle();
});
```

Comment: Okey, i want close dropdown when user click anything on website. And allows open only one dropdown. As in example: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/SeP8w/1/), just want to add to the menu from closing up when you click on the square.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
$(document).on('click', function(e){
    if($(e.target).parents('div.dropdown').length) {
        return false;
    }        
    $('.dropdown').toggleClass('active');
    return false;        
});
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/SeP8w/)

Updated for [multiple dropdowns](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/SeP8w/4/)

Comment: this code allows me to open dropdown (all lists) after click anything on website. Not the point.
As in example: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/SeP8w/1/), just want to add to the menu from closing up when you click on the square.